# Xamarin.forms unexpected alarm trigger in backgroud process in Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I'm just trying to get a multiple countdown counters, when it reaches individually to 0 I want to sound an alert (without any interaction from the user between one and the next).

The countdown is programmed, for instance, to 5, 4 and 7 minutes.
If it's seconds and the app works with the screen ON or just seconds there's no problem, but as soon as it's minutes, the screen turns off and the phone goes into Doze mode (I think), the resulting times are: 5, 6:26 and 9:58 (instead 5,4 and 7).

I've read a lot of user solutions that have been discussed here, but it doesn't work for me.
The phone runs Android v10.

The code to program the Alarm with SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle:

```
public void ProgAlarm(int nIntervalo) {
    var alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.Instance, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
    alarmIntent.PutExtra("Contador", nIntervalo);
    var pending = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(MainActivity.Instance, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

    MainActivity.alarM.SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup,
        SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime()+tiempos[nIntervalo]*1000, pending);
}
```

And the event triggerd to reprogram the alarm:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class AlarmReceiver: BroadcastReceiver {
   public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       DependencyService.Get<IVarios>().Beep();
       int actual=intent.GetIntExtra("Contador",-1);
       if (actual!=-1) DependencyService.Get<IVarios>().ProgAlarm(++actual);
    }
}
```

Before the Alarm I tried with PowerManager:

```
PowerManager pM = (PowerManager)GetSystemService(PowerService);
wakeLock=pM.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "CronoMultiple");
[...]
wakeLock.Acquire();
[...]
wakeLock.Release();
```

and with the flag: WakeLockFlags.AcquireCausesWakeup

But this only works when the screen was always ON, with flag .Partial, the screen turns off and the app stops and the counter doesn't work.  In the PC emulator it works (even with adb commands), but not on the phone.

Any solution without using a Service? (I'm new to Xamarin.forms).

Comment: You should put `ProgAlarm` into a Service,then it will run in background.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple sample ,it will alarm every 1 min:

interface **IVarios**

```
public interface IVarios
{
    void ProgAlarm(int minute);
}
```

in **MainActivity**,let it implement **IVarios** :

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity,IVarios
{
   public void ProgAlarm(int minute)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.Instance, typeof(LongRunningService));
        intent.PutExtra("Contador", minute);
        MainActivity.Instance.StartService(intent);
    }
}
```

in Android project,create **LongRunningService** :

```
[Service]
class LongRunningService : Service
{

    int minutes;
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
    }

    [return: GeneratedEnum]
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
       Android.Util.Log.Error("LongRunningService", "executed");
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(AlarmService);
        int min = intent.GetIntExtra("Contador", -1);
        minutes = min != -1 ? min : minutes;
        int anHour = minutes * 60 * 1000;   // Number of milliseconds

        long triggerAtTime = SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + anHour; 

        Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        manager.SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, triggerAtTime, pi);
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
}
```

in Android project,create **AlarmReceiver** :

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, typeof(LongRunningService));
        context.StartService(i);
    }
}
```

Then you could call it in your page like :

```
 DependencyService.Get<IVarios>().ProgAlarm(1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort but It doesn't work. 
For instance, the time for the crono are: 4,5 and 7 minutes, but if I let the screen to turn off (as I wanted) the alarm sounds in: 4, 6:37 and 10 minutes.
If I use the phone as usual while the app is running (I don't let the screen turn off) the alarm sounds at expected time: 4,5 and 7 minutes.

I think the 'sleep mode' it's 'stronger' than SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle...

Comment: If `SetExactAndAllowWhileIdle` is not exact enough,you could try to use [setAlarmClock()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent)),because AFAIK is not affected by Doze mode

Comment: With setAlarmClock instead of SetExactAndAllowWhileIde, doesn't work. Instantly jump OnReceive without waiting the necessary time:
AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo cInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(triggerAtTime, pi);
manager.SetAlarmClock(cInfo, pi);